# Calling specific function per dropdown menu button material ui - react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material dropdown menu component. I wanted to make it that when i click a button it runs a specific function for it i've utilized a condition on the state wherein in used the ID of that button and checks it and returns the said function. I have run it but nothing happens. Not sure if its a proper way of calling the said function or what i'm missing. I'm also new in React and Material. A could snippet is shown below. Thanks

```
function CADNavbar({
  handleClickRect,
  handleClickLine,
  handleClickCurve,
  handleClickText,
  handleClickDrag,
  handleClickSelect,
}) {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const navBarOptionsMap = [
    { name: 'Copy', Icon: CopyIconSVG },
    { name: 'Paste', Icon: PasteIcon },
    { name: 'Undo', Icon: UndoIcon },
    { name: 'Redo', Icon: RedoIcon },
    { name: 'Save', Icon: SaveIcon, handleEvent: () => {
      const blob = new Blob([paper.project.exportSVG({asString: true})], {type: "image/svg+xml"});
      saveAs(blob, "save.svg");
    }},
  ];

  const navBarToolsMap = [
    { Name: 'Line Tool', Icon: LineToolIcon, Handle: handleClickLine },
    { Name: 'Rect Tool', Icon: RectToolIcon, Handle: handleClickRect },
    { Name: 'Curve Tool', Icon: CurveToolIcon, Handle: handleClickCurve },
    { Name: 'Text Tool', Icon: TextToolIcon, Handle: handleClickText },
    { Name: 'Select Tool', Icon: SelectionToolIcon, Handle: handleClickSelect },
    { Name: 'DragTool', Icon: DragToolIcon, Handle: handleClickDrag },
  ];

  const hiddenFileInput = useRef(null);
  const handleClick = event => {
    hiddenFileInput.current.click();
  };
  const handleChange = event => {
    const fileUploaded = event.target.files[0];
    fileUploaded.text().then((value) => {
      let parsed = dxf.parseString(value);
      if (!parsed.tables) {
        for (let entity of parsed.entities) {
          entity.layer = entity.layer.trim();
        }
        const layer = parsed.entities[0].layer;
        parsed.tables = {layers: {[String(layer)]: {type: "LAYER", name: "0", flags: 0, colorNumber: 0}}}
      }
      console.dir(parsed);
      const svg = dxf.toSVG(parsed);
      const path = paper.project.importSVG(svg);
      path.strokeColor = "black";
      path.strokeWidth = 1;
    });
  };

  const handleMenuClick = (index, e) => {
    setAnchorEl({[index]: e.currentTarget});
  };
  const handleMenuClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };
  //Handles when a Submenu is clicked gets the index
  const handleSubMenuClick = (id, e) => {
    handleMenuClose();
    if (id == 1){
          return (
            <>
              <input
                type="file"
                ref={hiddenFileInput}
                onChange={handleChange}
                style={{display: 'none'}}
              />
            </>
          );
    } else {
      console.log(id)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <NavBarStyle>
        <NavBarLogo>
          {/*Container for Logo*/}
          <TempLogoSVG />
        </NavBarLogo>
        <NavTitleMenuBarCont>
          <NavDesignTitle>Design Title</NavDesignTitle>
            <NavMenuBar>
              {
                Object.keys(NavBarMenuItems).map((item, index) => (
                  <div classname={item} key={index}>
                    <Button
                      sx={{
                        color: grey[900], 
                        width: 20, 
                        height: 20,
                        fontSize: 12}}
                      onClick={(e) => handleMenuClick(index, e)}
                    >{item}</Button>
                    <Menu
                      anchorEl={anchorEl && anchorEl[index]}
                      keepMounted
                      open={anchorEl && Boolean(anchorEl[index])}
                      onClose={handleMenuClose}
                    >
                      {NavBarMenuItems[item].map((menuitems, menuindex) => (
                        <MenuItem
                          key={menuindex}
                          selected={menuitems == item}
                          onClick={(e) => handleSubMenuClick(menuitems.id, e)}
                        >
                          {menuitems.title}
                        </MenuItem>
                      ))}
                    </Menu>
                  </div>
                ))
              }
            </NavMenuBar>
        </NavTitleMenuBarCont>
        <NavSaveProfileCont>
          <NavToolsCont>
            {/* Tools */}
            {navBarToolsMap.map((_) => (
              <NavBarToolsItem
                handleEvent={_.Handle}
                Icon={_.Icon}></NavBarToolsItem>
            ))}
            {/* Quick Commands */}
            {navBarOptionsMap.map((item) => (
              <NavBarToolsItem Icon={item.Icon} handleEvent={item.handleEvent} />
            ))}
          </NavToolsCont>
          <NavChangeViewCont>
            <NavChangeViewBtn>
              <span>3D Viewer</span>
            </NavChangeViewBtn>
          </NavChangeViewCont>
          <NavToolsButton>
            <UserIconSVG />
          </NavToolsButton>
        </NavSaveProfileCont>
      </NavBarStyle>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've tried using by getting the ID of the drop down menu and used a condition to check the id and call the function.